# including properties from collection class with jackson json serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using jackson to serialize my pojo's.  Often, I have a collection class.  In this case I have some other properties on the collection class that need to be serialized.  For example for demonstration purposes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
public class Messages implements List<String> {
    @JsonProperty
    private String info = "hello";

    @JsonProperty
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

This serializes to:

`{
    "Messages": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}`

I desire for this to serialize to:

`{
    "info": "hello",
    "messages": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}`

Is there any thing that I can do to get jackson to serialize it the way that I desire?